# Price of an ITM American Put Spread

Tags: options

Should an ITM American put spread be equal to its intrinsic value as the options could then be exercised for the intrinsic value instantly? There is not more the spread would be able to make. This isn't observed in practise though. Wondering if someone could clarify.